# Protect Excel workbook WITH password AND share with NON-DEFAULT advanced parameters

Tags: microsoft-excel, passwords, microsoft-excel-2007

In Excel 2007 it seems like I can do one of the two things separately, but not together:

1. I can share the workbook **with non-default advanced parameters** but **without a password protection** (*Review->Changes->Share Workbook->Advanced*, specify non-default advanced parameters, then *Review->Changes->Share Workbook->Editing->Allow changes by more than one user at the same time* = Checked)
2. I can **protect the workbook with password** and **share it with default advanced parameters** (*Review->Changes->Protect and Share Workbook*)

But I need to combine both, i.e. **protect with password** and **share with non-default advanced parameters**. The problem is that:

1. If I do step 1 first, then in step 2 password field is disabled, so I can only protect without a password, which defeats the purpose of protection.
2. If I do step 2 first, then step 1 is not possible entirely because *Review->Changes->Share Workbook* is disabled.

Is there a way to overcome that without resorting to VBA (so that an ordinary user can do that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved the problem myself. Here is how this can be accomplished from GUI without VBA, it takes a rather non-intuitive sequence of steps, but it works:

1. First remember to protect the worksheets that you need protected, preferably using a password, but this is just a reminder, you can proceed without protecting individual worksheets if you so desire, it's just that you won't be able to protect them later once you protect the entire workbook without first unprotecting it, so now it is time to do it.
2. Go to **Review->Changes->Share Workbook**, *Editing* tab, check *Allow changes by more than one user at the same time* checkbox, **do not** press *OK* button yet, do not close the window.
3. Switch to **Advanced** tab in the same *Share Workbook* window and specify **only first** advanced parameter (**Track changes**), if you need a non-default value for it (default is "Keep change history for 30 days", non defaults values are either "Keep change history for X days" where X is not 30 or "Don't keep change history"). Fun fact: the maximum number of days you can specify here is 2^15-1 = 32767.
4. Don't waste your time setting the rest of the advanced parameters for now even if you need them, they won't be remembered after what we are about to do in step 6, you will have an opportunity to set them in step 8 later.
5. Press *OK* in the same *Share Workbook* window, agree when Excel asks you to save the file.
6. Now a non-intuitive part: Go to **Review->Changes->Share Workbook**, *Editing* tab, **uncheck** *Allow changes by more than one user at the same time* checkbox, Press *OK* button. Press *OK* in the confirmation message box.
7. Go to **Review->Changes->Protect and Share Workbook**, check *Sharing with track changes* checkbox, enter your password in *Password (optional)* edit box, press *OK* button, confirm your password in *Confirm Password* dialog box, press *OK* in the confirmation message box.
8. Go to **Review->Changes->Share Workbook->** for a third time, switch to *Advanced* tab and specify the rest of the advanced parameter as you please (notice that they will be enabled, unlike the first advanced parameter, which is disabled).
9. Save the file.

**Important note**: If you have performed the sequence above but then needed to un-protect and un-share the workbook, make some changes to it and **re-protect and re-share**, you only need to repeat steps 7,8 and 9, not the entire sequence.

Tested to work in Excel 2007.

Remember that if you happen to be an unfortunate user of the most recent version of Excel, you will first need to jump through some hoops to get the legacy sharing function re-enabled, as the Microsoft is trying to force you to use their idiotic cloud-based sharing instead that I never needed and never asked for. Sure it is "convenient" as they advertise it, but only until you lose Internet connectivity, then you will be very-very sad. The fix for that problem can be found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-happened-to-shared-workbooks-150fc205-990a-4763-82f1-6c259303fe05